# Access dynamic nested children from parent

Tags: reactjs

React community.

I have a problem when I try to read a child's props from parents.

The problem is I can't read their children.

Here is my sample code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k1juqm

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you mean the `Tabs` component, it has one child and its `Render`, and it logs it correctly as I see.

Comment: Yep but I want to read nested components inside `Render`